# Fetch data from mysql by converting it's timestamp to unix time

Tags: php, mysql

This will be done with PHP.

I basically want to get the number of rows that were inserted 30 minutes ago.

I have a time field on my table which is type TIMESTAMP and on update it's set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

The date is stored in this format:

```
2011-05-27 04:29:17
```

My query is supposed to look something like this, however i just can't do it

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) < '.time().'-1800
```

Where time() is PHP's function that fetches the UNIX time.

What it should basically do is print me the number of rows inserted from now to 30 minutes ago, but i just can't seem to make it work.

Can somebody help?

Small edit:
Another problem i am seeing is that php's function time() displays the unix time which is UTC. The time stored in mysql is probably GMT i.e whatever my computer's time/timezone is set to.

Comment: I am having the same issue that dikidera mentions in his "Small edit". What I am looking for is where php is getting its time() vs where MySQL is getting the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I really do not give a damn if I am using UTC or not, I just need them to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get rows stored from now to `30 mins` ago by simply using:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 minute)
```

Usage of `UTC_TIMESTAMP` is just an example if you're storing your date/time data as `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`, you can probably use `NOW()` if necessary, depends on what you're storing really.

****EDIT****
Removed bad pointers and fixed example :)

Comment: @tradyblix: No need to change the `COUNT(*)` .

Comment: Strangely enough, when i run this query directly via PHPMyAdmin i get all the rows in the table, which were btw inserted a day ago, not 30 minutes ago

Comment: @tradyblix: What you say about `COUNT()` is plain wrong in MySQL. MySQL is actually running `COUNT(*)` faster than `COUNT(field)`. Just try it out with a table with a few million rows.

Comment: @ypercube my bad, fixed for everyone's sake :)

Comment: @dikidera: Try it, using `NOW()` instead of `UTC_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: You can also use: `time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute `

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you really need your computer's timezone to be different than UTC? why not just set it to UTC & save yourself the confusion? If that doesn't work, just use dateadd() on mysql to convert your mysql timestamp to UTC when checking?
2. My suggestion would be to write a small function to convert the mysql timestamp to your PHP timestamp format & load it into mysql. Then all you need to do is to call tmstamp(time_stamp) instead of time_stamp in your query. You can do the reverse too i.e. Convert PHP's "30 minutes ago" timestamp to mysql format and rerun your query (probably easier).

Usually it's just a formatting issue. It's not standardized across programs.

Comment: Well the requirement is to store the time in MySQL in UTC..and i am very bad with timezones..
But you see, i do not have access to the application that is storing the data in mysql, so mysql must add it's own timestamp.